# Borel - Caratheodory Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

If $f$ is a complex-valued function analytic on $\{z:\vert z \vert \leqq r \}$, then for $\vert z \vert <r $,

$$
\vert f(z) \vert \leqq \frac{2\vert z \vert}{2-\vert z \vert} \sup\{\Re f(w): \vert w \vert=\vert z \vert\}+\frac{r+\vert z \vert}{r-\vert z \vert}\vert f(0) \vert.
$$

Comment: The $2-|z|$ in the denominator after the inequality sign looks like a typo to me. Could you check it, please? There are LaTeX glitches to put right as well; in particular, sup and Re shouldn't be italic.